# PHP insert/validation/required field trouble

Tags: php, forms, insert, field, required

Ok, I have a problem with the following insert statement: (Tell me if you want the whole code)

```
$required = array('exam_id', 'subject', 'exam_date');

$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
    if ( !empty($_POST['insert'])) {
        $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Exam (exam_id, subject, exam_date) VALUES 
                        ($_POST[uexam_id],$_POST[usubject],$_POST[uexam_date])";
        $result = mysql_query($InsertQuery, $con);
        if (!$result) { $error = true; }
    }
} 
if ($error) {
    die ("All fields are required! <a href='examisud.php'> Back to Form </a>");
}
```

Ok, so essentially I want all fields (exam, subject & exam_date) to be required fields. If the user doesn't fill in a field, an error pops up asking them to go back and refill all fields).
In that way, it works. However, when I test it and fill in all fields, the error also pops up too, so regardless of what happens, the insert isn't working correctly and any attempts so far i've made to change it result in fields being inserted into, but the validation no longer works.
Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the values of $_POST[uexam_id], $_POST[usubject] and $_POST[uexam_date] to make sure they are valid? Seems like you should have single quotes around 'usubject', 'uexam_date' etc. Also, you are open to sql injection with the way you are doing this. You need to filter out the values before you pass them to the query.

Comment: Test it before you actually execute the query! So check if all elements are present and valid once you complete that check than run the query!

Comment: Triad, Nah, it's a personal project, no worries of SQL injection! I keep forgetting to add that to questions.
And I have tried it with single quotes around uexam_id, usubject, etc, I still get the same issue.
And I am sure the values are valid, I had an old system without validation or required fields were the whole thing worked perfectly, as soon as I started using foreach and the array and error, this started happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run 3 queries instead of trying to run the query after the test...

```
$required = array('uexam_id', 'usubject', 'uexam_date');

$error = false;
//first check all required fields are not empty. if post has values
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    foreach($required as $field) 
        if ( empty($_POST[$field])) 
            $error = true;           
    //a field was empty, show error
    if ($error) {
        die ("All fields are required! <a href='examisud.php'> Back to Form </a>");
    }
    //no error - try the query
    else
    {
        $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Exam (exam_id, subject, exam_date) VALUES 
                        ($_POST[uexam_id],$_POST[usubject],$_POST[uexam_date])";
        $result = mysql_query($InsertQuery, $con) or die('query Failure:'. mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Also as a side note as im sure others will mention, mysql is deprecated, please look to using mysqli in the future. Also I notice the required fields don't have the 'u' before them as the query does. I assume this is a mistake?

Comment: You're onto something! But all I get when I go to the page is the error "All fields are required!" it doesn't even show me the form at all :/

Comment: put and if(!empty($_POST)) before the foreach - editied my answer to apply.

Comment: i think your real problem is the discrepancy between the required fields array and the POST values you're trying to insert being different.

Comment: The POST values are like that because of my form, they are identified as uexam_id, etc.
I tried your method buddy and it doesn;t work for me, I dunno what to tell ya :/
I still get "All fields are required" when I navigate to the page. Although when I go back to the form, it goes to the form, however the fields won't enter to the database, either if all fields are entered or if only one is entered.

Comment: ...ya you can't check against fields that don't exist. If the required field is uexam_id, you're always going to get error as true since you're checking for exam_id. Don't know what you expected to happen. Updated my answer to what you say fields are.

Comment: I got it working! Thanks! I'll post an answer when it lets me in 8 hours.

Comment: Good deal, feel free to make this the accepted answer. :)

Comment: LOL, just as you were posting the "ya you can't check against fields..." I was putting u in front of the array values.
And sure thing, will do! Also, i'm a n00b to this site, how do I rep you???

Comment: You did it. Thanks. We all start as beginners. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

Keep everything else the same but add a break statement as follows:

```
//Previous code, then

        if (!$result) { $error = true; }
    break;
    }
}
if ($error) {
    die ("All fields are required! <a href='examisud.php'> Back to Form </a>");
}
```

Your foreach loop may continue to run without a break statement, so even after a successful query (all 3 fields filled, and $error = false), if the query of the next iteration fails, now $error = true, hence the execution of "die".